# how to select few words from text area in selenium rc

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide

steps:
1. i uploaded file using browse option.
2. uploaded file content displayed in non-editable format
3. now i have to select few words.

for this i used mouseMoveAt (100,200) mouseDown() mouseMoveAt (150,250) mouseMoveUp().
This is not working..

Can anyone can give sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but here's my take - 
You can use `selenium.getText();` for retrieving the text on a page and storing it in a variable. You can use this variable, which you can verify for correctness.
Here's an example syntax:

```
String var = selenium.getText(your_identifier_for_text);
```

Further, if you need to extract and verify just a portion of the text contained in `var`, you can use Java string functions.